# Why is setting the @ISA directly not working in this example?

Tags: perl, oop

I have these two modules :

```
package G1;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {
        one => 1,
        two => 2,
        three => 3
    };
    bless $self,$class;
    return $self;
}

sub three {
    my $self = shift;
    print "G1 green is ",$self->{three};
}

1;

package G2;

our @ISA = qw(G1);
#use base qw(G1);

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new();
    $self->{three} = 90;
    bless $self,$class;
    return $self;
}

sub three {
    my $self = shift;
    print "G2 rox!\n";
    $self->SUPER::three();
}

1;
```

and the following script:

```
use G2;

my $ob = G2->new();
$ob->three();
```

When I run the script, it produces the following error :

```
Can't locate object method "new" via package "G2" at G2.pm line 8.
```

If I replace the `@ISA` line with `use base`, the script works. I'm trying to override some methods and call the original ones after. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you ever get an error, *with anything*, first check if you have "use strict; use warnings;" and then try again :)  Chances are you'll have a better idea of what went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because G2.pm needs to include a `use G1;` line. Without that, `G1.pm` is never being loaded. If you run with warnings, Perl will tell you this:

```
$ perl -w t.pl
Can't locate package G1 for @G2::ISA at t.pl line 1.
Can't locate package G1 for @G2::SUPER::ISA at G2.pm line 8.
Can't locate package G1 for @G2::SUPER::ISA at G2.pm line 8.
Can't locate object method "new" via package "G2" at G2.pm line 8.
```

Notice all the *can't locate package G1…* errors.

And to be clear, `use base 'G1'` works because that also does a `use G1`.

Comment: That was stupid of me, but no matter how many times I read over the code, I haven't noticed that. Thanks!

Comment: Always 'use warnings' and 'use strict'; those two will save you countless hours of debugging.

Answer (score 2):

G2 needs to know about G1, not just the name. Add

```
require G1;
```

to G2.pm.